# Limits on ADO connection execute queries

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I have a SQL script that does quite a few updates. When I retrieve the script (in a Classic ASP page) from a text file and attempt to execute it, it does not appear to apply all the updates I expect yet if I copy and paste the content into Management Studio, the query works fine. I cannot work out why this might be the case. Is there a limit as to how many statements/operations you can include in such a script?

Also the execute command `oConn.Execute strSql` does not fail, it just moves to the next line of classic ASP code. Is there any way I can test for errors?

Comment: I think I have solved the first part of this - I had a SELECT statement halfway through the script for debugging purposes which, I assume, must have been causing the script to return that result set before executing the remainder of the script. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you use the `GO` batch separator anywhere in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, but have you tried wrapping your code in `TRANSACTION` blocks?  Very useful if things go wrong.

As for error handling, [you can refer to the `@@ERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx)...

```sql
DECLARE @ErrorVar INT

RAISERROR(N'Message', 16, 1);
IF @@ERROR <> 0
    -- This PRINT statement prints 'Error = 0' because
    -- @@ERROR is reset in the IF statement above.
    PRINT N'Error = ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS NVARCHAR(8));
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, this set me on the right track. I wrapped the script in a transaction then checked for errors at the end and, if I encountered any, I rolled back the transaction and returned the error.

Answer (score 1):

Paul set me on the right track here, thank you. I've been coding SQL for years but confess I have dabbled only a little in the world of transactions. After the code below I put other stats and the failure message into a table that I interrogate in the ASP code after calling the script.

`BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  --My long update script placed in here

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SET @FailMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Failed at line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar) + '.'
  END
END CATCH`